# magento database sql not working

Tags: php, mysql, oop, magento, zend-framework

So do not have an idea why this function is not working? i am trying to select all the ids from the table but nothing is selected.

```
       public function jobsArray()
      {
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('Envato_CustomConfig_Job');
        $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT id FROM Envato_CustomConfig_Job");

        $rows = array();
        foreach($result as $record) {
            $rows = ('value'=>$record, 'label'=>$record);
        }
        return $rows;
      }
```

this function below works fine, I need the function above to do the same as teh function below.

```
  public function toOptionArray()
  {
    return array(
      array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'one'),
      array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
      array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three'),            
      array('value'=>4, 'label'=>'Four')                     
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

You're only selecting a single item (`id`, but later, I assume you're expecting an ID and a value).

```
    $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT id FROM Envato_CustomConfig_Job");
```

`record` is an array from your SQL query, so you should be treating it as such. eg. `$record['id']`

`$rows` you want as an array, but you're overwriting it each time, so `$rows[] =` makes more sense

Something like:

```
public function jobsArray()
{
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('Envato_CustomConfig_Job');
    $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT id, label FROM Envato_CustomConfig_Job");

    $rows = array();
    foreach($result as $record) {
        $rows[] = array('value'=>$record['id'], 'label'=>$record['label']);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Please insert the required `array` keyword as well; `('value'=>$record['id'])` is not valid php

Comment: nope still dont work, i added the word array before the value bracket.

Comment: still not grabbing the results.

Comment: If you var_dump $record in your loop, what do you get?  Also, I'm assuming you do have a connector set up for Envato_CustomConfig_Job - otherwise you should probably be using core_read

Comment: it works fine when i used core_read....what do you mean by connector? @DouglasRadburn

Comment: You can define your own resources - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-to-connect-another-database-from-magento

Answer (score 2):

Try using the core read/write resource. Change

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('Envato_CustomConfig_Job');
```

To

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
```